# Is it okay to use “Off This—“ in a spec script?

Tags: creative-writing, formatting, screenwriting, script

I feel like it’s a great tool for transitioning scenes.

Off the Sargent’s grimacing face—

Off the dead cheerleader’s tramp stamp—

But is this considered camera direction? 
Is this too specific for a spec?
Or no?

Thanks! 
Marc

Answer (score 1):

I think it is some kind of directorial or camera direction, and I don't recognize it as a standard one. If it is what I think it means, you are directing, and wasting a line (which counts as **time** in a script, and costs you a line of dialogue for example). I say "wasting" because what else could happen? How is this different than what the director will imagine anyway? And if it **is** different, the director will go with **their** visual imagination over yours, anyway.

Are you talking about a [Graphic Match Cut?](https://sites.google.com/a/colgate.edu/fmst-terminology/graphic-match) (Or Action Match Cut.)

That would still be a directorial prerogative, but you could mention it to note to the director such a match exists. Panning away or focusing on something else or some standard camera direction should be left to the director, none of them should be mentioned.

Comment: Off— just means: The last thing we see before the cut. Are you unfamiliar with this term? Maybe it’s not as popular as I assumed... Check out the Season 1 Episode 1 script for The Killing. (great screenplay) Keyword search the word “Off”. The writer uses it a lot. I realize that it’s not a spec. So, I was wondering where to draw the line. Your comment has reaffirmed what I thought. I’ll probably leave it out. Thanks